# Make a browser in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am completely new to Xcode and iOS developing in general.

Basically I have a task of making a simple browser application for the iPad/iPhone/iPod. This browser application will only be able to access a single specific website.

I have found many tutorials for making browsers in Xcode. 
For example, this one: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vpq8r-HHwZA

However, there are a few requirements that I need that are not included in the tutorial:

1. The browser needs to have a unique identifier. I need a way for that specific website to detect that this browser is unique to itself (and not Firefox, Safari, etc). Is there any way to set a unique ID for the browser that I am going to make?
2. The browser needs to open up automatically at a certain URL.

Are these two features possible? Can anybody point me in the proper direction?

Comment: You can watch this youtube video https://youtu.be/XWhcnIxrtMk

Comment: It is a series video so you will have to wait for new videos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In terms of overriding the web browser's identifier, I tried altering the "User-Agent" header field of the NSUrlRequest, but UIWebView's `loadRequest` replaced it (which is a reasonable thing for them to do, IMHO). So, I'm not sure if you can change the browser identifier, but I would have thought that you could either (a) set a cookie that the web site could check; (b) set some different HTTP header (you'd just coordinate this with your web master ... I don't even know if this is appropriate); or (c) you could do something low tech like adding a parameter to the URL coming from the app? I don't know. Hopefully others can advise you better on this point.
2. In terms of loading a certain URL, in `viewDidLoad` just invoke UIWebView's `loadRequest` using your preferred URL.
3. If your goal is to keep them at that web site, you could just not present them with an editable address bar, in which case they could only follow links available on the site. Or alternatively implement UIWebViewDelegate's `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` to make sure that any web requests stay within the preferred web site.